# SELECT .. INTO to create a table in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I want to use `SELECT INTO` to make a temporary table in one of my functions. `SELECT INTO` works in SQL but not PL/pgSQL.

This statement creates a table called mytable (If `orig_table` exists as a relation):

```
SELECT *
INTO TEMP TABLE mytable
FROM orig_table;
```

But put this function into PostgreSQL, and you get the error: `ERROR:  "temp" is not a known variable`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION whatever()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO TEMP TABLE mytable
    FROM orig_table;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I can `SELECT INTO` a variable of type `record` within PL/pgSQL, but then I have to define the structure when getting data out of that record. `SELECT INTO` is really simple - automatically creating a table of the same structure of the `SELECT` query. Does anyone have any explanation for why this doesn't work inside a function?

It seems like `SELECT INTO` works differently in PL/pgSQL, because you can select into the variables you've declared. I don't want to declare my temporary table structure, though. I wish it would just create the structure automatically like it does in SQL.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytable AS
SELECT *
FROM orig_table;
```

Per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html

> CREATE TABLE AS is functionally similar to SELECT INTO. CREATE TABLE AS is the recommended syntax, since this form of SELECT INTO is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the INTO clause differently. Furthermore, CREATE TABLE AS offers a superset of the functionality provided by SELECT INTO.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had solved this problem before, and I remember that sentence from the postgresql docs. I just had totally forgotten about CREATE TABLE AS.