# Save query as a table with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, navicat

How do you save a postgresql query output as a table? Similar to the maketable query within Access. I want to be able to join other tables to the query output and making a new table would make life good. I am using Navicat to execute queries.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT .. INTO to create a table in PL/pgSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979154/select-into-to-create-a-table-in-pl-pgsql)

Answer (score 16):

If you have a `select statement` you can execute a CTAS

```
CREATE TABLE <table name> AS (
SELECT STATEMENT
)
```