# Is there any significant difference between using SELECT ... FROM ... INTO syntax instead of the standard SELECT ... INTO ... FROM?

Tags: postgresql, select-into

I was creating a function following an example from a database class which included the creation of a temporary variable (base_salary) and using a SELECT INTO to calculate its value later.
However, I did not realize I used a different order for the syntax (SELECT ... FROM ... INTO base_salary) and the function could be used later without any visible issues (values worked as expected).
Is there any difference in using "SELECT ... FROM ... INTO" syntax order? I tried looking about it in the PostgreSQL documentation but found nothing about it. Google search did not provide any meaningful information neither. Only thing I found related to it was from MySQL documentation, which only mentioned about supporting the different order in an older version.

Comment: A difference there is not.

Comment: Are you talking about plain SQL or storing data in variables in PL/pgSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) of pl/pgsql:

> The `INTO` clause can appear almost anywhere in the SQL command.
> Customarily it is written either just before or just after the list of
> *select_expressions* in a `SELECT` command, or at the end of the command for other command types. It is recommended that you follow
> this convention in case the PL/pgSQL parser becomes stricter in future
> versions.

Notice that in (non-procedural) SQL, there is also a [`SELECT INTO` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) which [works like `CREATE TABLE AS`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11979154/1048572), in this version the `INTO` must come right after the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thanks! Guess that, since there is no difference, will better stick to the standard then.

Answer (score 0):

I always use SELECT ... INTO ... FROM , I believe that is the standard supported notation

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

I would recommend using this, also if there are any updates or if the other version might become unsupported as you mentioned...

Comment: If that is to create a new table, the SQL standard only specifies `create table new_table as select ....` - another example of the poor quality of w3fools.